# Program loading files however not having any values changed

Tags: python, file-upload, save, load, caesar-cipher

This is a basic program that is supposed to take a string from either a pre-made file or to take user input then encrypt it and save it to a file using a caesar cipher.

My issue is that for some reason when I run the program and select the 'Load File' option it will go through all the code without any error messages however the writing on the the .txt file will not have been encrypted, does anyone know how to remedy this?

For a neater layout of the code here's a Pastebin link:
http://pastebin.com/dJJ1M4g7

```
def main():

    #if they want to save the file after the encrypting if statement
    ans = input("Would you like to save to a file of read a file, press w or     r").lower()

    if ans == "w":
        text = input("What is your text you want to enter").lower()

        save_file(caeser(text))

    elif ans == "r":

        caeser(load_file())

# organise loop & function
def caeser(text):
        shift = int(input("How much would you like to shift?: "))
        shifted_list = []
        for letter in text:
            character_lower = letter.lower()
            ASCII = ord(character_lower)
            shift = shift % 26
            shifted_letter = ASCII + shift
            shifted_char = chr(shifted_letter)
            shift_loop = shifted_letter - 26
            shift_loop_char = chr(shift_loop)
            if shifted_letter >= 97 and shifted_letter <= 122:
                shifted_list.append(shifted_char)
                text = ''.join(shifted_list)
            elif shift_loop >= 97 and shift_loop <= 122:
                shifted_list.append(shift_loop_char)
                text = ''.join(shifted_list)
            else:
                shifted_list.append(character_lower)
                text = ''.join(shifted_list)

            encrypted = text

        return encrypted

def save_file(text):
    name = input("Enter filename")
    file = open(name, "w")
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

# error protection needs to be added
def load_file():
    name = input("what is your file name? (include .txt)")
    file = open(name, "r")
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
caeser(load_file())
```

add a save file around...

Answer (score 0):

*load_file* is not doing a write, so you can either do what you did for the write option

```
save_file(load_file())
```

or call the save inside the load function

```
save_file(text)
```